# Installing Scrapy on ubuntu 14.04 fails

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy

I'm getting error installing Scrapy on my ubuntu box. I'm using pip to install Scrapy. I'm aware that it needs setuptools to be installed. I got that installed using the script provided in setuptools website.

```
reading manifest file 'Twisted.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

writing manifest file 'Twisted.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport

copying twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport

copying twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/winsock_pointers.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport

copying twisted/test/raiser.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twisted/test

copying twisted/runner/portmap.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twisted/runner

copying twisted/python/sendmsg.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twisted/python

running build_ext

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c conftest.c -o conftest.o

building 'twisted.runner.portmap' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/twisted

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/twisted/runner

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c twisted/runner/portmap.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/twisted/runner/portmap.o

twisted/runner/portmap.c:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include <Python.h>

                    ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/Twisted/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-4QNuNV-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/Twisted
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Any Idea where the process goes wrong? I've got gcc and g++ installed already.

Comment: It's not a best practice, but have you tried with sudo ?

Comment: @chilliq Oh yeah I was trying that with root privileges.

Comment: I think it will be helpful, if you provide commands, which you typed in the terminal.

Comment: @chilliq- I used: pip install Scrapy

Comment: Have a look at this then: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/ubuntu.html#topics-ubuntu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the error `fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory` it looks like python development headers are not installed. Try this command and then try to install again.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

For installing `libevent` library apply this command,

```
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
```

Comment: Thanks, the installation worked fine. But I'm getting another error executing scrapy from command line.

Comment: try scrapy --version. And please accept the answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: washed- It actually resolved part of the problem. I'm still struggling though! Python throws traceback errors.  from scrapy.tests.spiders import FollowAllSpider
ImportError: No module named tests.spiders

Comment: This problem is not in your current problem's context, which is installing scrapy. you can post another question and get help.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out on ubuntu 14.04 by (A) actually following the scrapy docs for installing on ubuntu, then (B) an error that a lot of others were getting, by following a S/O solution [Error while starting new scrapy project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304886/error-while-starting-new-scrapy-project)

**(A)** http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/ubuntu.html#topics-ubuntu

then

**(B)**

```
sudo pip install pyasn1 --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Right after installing Fedora 23 that's what I did (may works on Ubuntu):

```
[root@x ~]# pip install scrapy
[root@x ~]# dnf install python-cffi
[root@x ~]# dnf install openssl-devel
[root@x ~]# dnf install gcc
[root@x ~]# dnf install redhat-rpm-config
[root@x ~]# dnf install libxml
[root@x ~]# dnf install libxml2-devel
[root@x ~]# dnf install libxml-devel
[root@x ~]# dnf install glib2-devel gnet2-devel
[root@x ~]# dnf install libxslt-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install python3-scrapy
```

I have tried this ..and it worked for me.
(You should have the ssh installed)