# Error in the installation of scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, pip, gnu

I just tried to run a simple

```
sudo pip install scrapy
```

and after the download of every component it gives me an error:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-s37cTl/cffi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-62NAJB-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-s37cTl/cffi
```

I satisfy all the dependecies, don't know what can be.
I run Debian 7.

Thanks!

EDIT: I paste the whole installations terminal output:

```
 :~$ sudo pip install scrapy
    Collecting scrapy
  Using cached Scrapy-0.24.5-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting cssselect>=0.9 (from scrapy)
  Using cached cssselect-0.9.1.tar.gz
Collecting queuelib (from scrapy)
  Using cached queuelib-1.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyOpenSSL (from scrapy)
  Using cached pyOpenSSL-0.14.tar.gz
Collecting w3lib>=1.8.0 (from scrapy)
  Using cached w3lib-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Collecting Twisted>=10.0.0 (from scrapy)
  Using cached Twisted-15.0.0.tar.bz2
Collecting six>=1.5.2 (from scrapy)
  Using cached six-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cryptography>=0.2.1 (from pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
  Using cached cryptography-0.8.tar.gz
Collecting zope.interface>=3.6.0 (from Twisted>=10.0.0->scrapy)
  Using cached zope.interface-4.1.2.tar.gz
Collecting pyasn1 (from cryptography>=0.2.1->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
  Using cached pyasn1-0.1.7.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from cryptography>=0.2.1->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Collecting enum34 (from cryptography>=0.2.1->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
  Using cached enum34-1.0.4.tar.gz
Collecting cffi>=0.8 (from cryptography>=0.2.1->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
  Using cached cffi-0.9.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from cffi>=0.8->cryptography>=0.2.1->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Installing collected packages: cffi, enum34, pyasn1, zope.interface, cryptography, six, Twisted, w3lib, pyOpenSSL, queuelib, cssselect, scrapy
  Running setup.py install for cffi
    building '_cffi_backend' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DUSE__THREAD -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/c/_cffi_backend.o
    c/_cffi_backend.c:13:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-tIHlcr/cffi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-dPM9YP-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

    running build

    running build_py

    creating build

    creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.7

    creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/cffi

    copying cffi/lock.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/cffi

    copying cffi/model.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/cffi

    copying cffi/api.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/cffi

    copying cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/cffi

    copying cffi/gc_weakref.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/cffi

    copying cffi/vengine_cpy.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/cffi

    copying cffi/verifier.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/cffi

    copying cffi/ffiplatform.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/cffi

    copying cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/cffi

    copying cffi/cparser.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/cffi

    copying cffi/commontypes.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/cffi

    copying cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/cffi

    running build_ext

    building '_cffi_backend' extension

    creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7

    creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/c

    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DUSE__THREAD -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/c/_cffi_backend.o

    c/_cffi_backend.c:13:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory

    compilation terminated.

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-tIHlcr/cffi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-dPM9YP-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-tIHlcr/cffi
```

Comment: Can you provide the traceback? you can try the solution here and let know the result http://stackoverflow.com/a/25216266/1113211

Comment: I have installed python-dev but not libevent-dev. I installed it and now it works, I am not sure wether that is for the libevent or for the libffi-dev, either way thank you very much, all good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mint 17, I was able to install Scrapy after installing following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
```

Comment: I lacked the libffi-dev package, didn't know it was required (they should update the requirement page I guess). Now it works good, thanks!

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-dev as well.

Comment: @kolba329 your hint of also installing the package `python-dev` finally made things work for me on Lubuntu 14.04 when dealing with a similar ffi/cffi-based pip-installation issue; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS

```
yum install libffi libffi-devel
```

then

```
pip install cffi
pip install Scrapy
```