# Error while starting new scrapy project

Tags: python, scrapy

I have installed Scrapy using Ubuntu packages provided in the Scrapy website.
But on starting a Scrapy project

```
scrapy startproject test
```

I am getting error message as.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 5,
 in <module>
     from pkg_resources import load_entry_point   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3084,
 in <module>
        File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3070, in _call_aside
        File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3097, in _initialize_master_working_set
        File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 653, in _build_master
        File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 666, in _build_from_requirements
        File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 844, in resolve
      pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (pyasn1 0.1.7 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages),
 Requirement.parse('pyasn1>=0.1.8'), set(['pyasn1-modules']))
```

Please help me solve this error. I am running Python 2.7.6

Comment: Looks like you are missing a dependency. Try install pyasn1

Comment: Just type scrapy in the terminal and let me know the results

Comment: 'pip install pyasn1` - possibly with `sudo` before it if you get an error message.

Comment: I tried pip install pysan1 and sudo pip install pysan1, I am getting error as 

Downloading/unpacking pysan1

  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pysan1

Cleaning up...

No distributions at all found for pysan1

Comment: I just entered scrapy in the terminal , but I am getting the same error message as before :

pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (pyasn1 0.1.7 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages),
 Requirement.parse('pyasn1>=0.1.8'), set(['pyasn1-modules']))

Answer (score 26):

According to the error:

```
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (pyasn1 0.1.7 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages),
Requirement.parse('pyasn1>=0.1.8'), set(['pyasn1-modules']))
```

The required pyasn1 version should be ***greater or equal to 0.1.8*** and you currently have installed in your global py2.7 dist-packages ***v0.1.7***.

`sudo pip install pyasn1 --upgrade` will update your current pyasn1 package to the latest version and should solve the problem.

**Note**: you may wish to check that other projects or applications you have that depend on this library are still functioning correctly.

As a solution to the above notice, please have a look at creating `virtualenv`'s for your python project as this will isolate dependant packages to your project (global ones remain unaffected). more information on virtualenv can be found [HERE](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: No pip on Ubuntu, see z.neal's answer below, it works!

Answer (score 0):

first you should visit  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyasn1/
then download pyasn1-0.1.9-py2.7.egg (md5)
and then execute easy_install pyasn1-0.1.9-py2.7.egg
it works on my computer (CentOS 7)

Comment: please post how this will solve the problem. then referecens

Comment: This is the right answer!  It solved the problem super easy on my Ubuntu machine as well! Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

i just had exactly the same problem. 
it's something with not updated dependencies. 
try something like this:

sudo apt-get autoremove python

then:

apt-get install python

apt-get install python-scrapy

Comment: unecessary removal of python here.